# setting up WSFC for AlwaysOn with one node acting as read replica for both instnaces ( AWS EC2)

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I am trying to setup WSFC so that I can configure AlwaysOn. I have 3 nodes(A,B,C) and each has one instance (1, 2 and 3).  I am trying to setup WSFC between A and C and another WSFC between B and C nodes where C node will only be used as read replica for Node A and Node B instance.

I setup WSFC (ClusterBC) between Node B and Node C and I was able to configure AAG for inst2(on node B) with database resides on read replica node(node C) instance (inst3).

Now, when I tried to setup WSFC between node A and node C, I am getting an error that cluster node C is already part of cluster.

How can I setup WSFC so I can setup AAF for inst1 running on Node A and read replica(inst3) running on Node C?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are confusing the WSFC configuration with the AG configuration. A server (and its instances) may belong to only one WSFC. An AG can use any of the nodes/instances of the WSFC.

You need a WSFC with all 3 servers (A, B, and C). This will allow you to 1) create an AG with nodes B and C and 2) create an AG with nodes A and C. Read replicas for each AG can be configured independently. A database can belong to only one AG so the assumption is the AGs host different databases. Also keep in mind that a replica role will change after a failover. C could become the primary at some point for either of the AGs and you may also need to configure the other node(s) as a read-only replica in the secondary role if desired.

Answer (score 0):

All three servers must be in the same Windows cluster. You can then configure Always-On availability groups as you want between your SQL Server instances.

Just keep in mind Windows Failover cluster quorum requirements: If node A or Node B can't communicate with on of the other 2 nodes, it will go offline, as well as the databases part of an availability group on it.

For more information about cluster quorum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum#general-recommendations-for-quorum-configuration